# How to use Power Management Functions (PowerEnuimerate) to get power settings

Tags: c#, .net, windows, desktop

I need my application to read things like the amount of time the system will wait before shutting off the display, or going to sleep, or going into hibernate. As far as I can tell, I need to use the Power Management Functions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373163%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) In particular, it looks like I need to use the PowerEnumerate method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I'm really confused about how to do this. First, I'm doing this in C#, and the code looks to be C++. Second, the C++ code seems to not really tell you how to specifically read the different time outs I want.

Note, I'm new to windows programming and C#. Most of my experience has been in Java and Android.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found an [example on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/4b3cbaa7-00dc-4dc1-bb03-00c4485d2111/) for using the `PowerEnumerate` function in VB.

I have converted the example to C#, and added the Friendly Name to the output of each Video setting in the loop. You can change the `GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP` to one of the other subgroups to see the other settings.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace TestProject
{
    class PowerEnumerator
    {
        private static Guid NO_SUBGROUP_GUID = new Guid("fea3413e-7e05-4911-9a71-700331f1c294");
        private static Guid GUID_DISK_SUBGROUP = new Guid("0012ee47-9041-4b5d-9b77-535fba8b1442");
        private static Guid GUID_SYSTEM_BUTTON_SUBGROUP = new Guid("4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347");
        private static Guid GUID_PROCESSOR_SETTINGS_SUBGROUP = new Guid("54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00");
        private static Guid GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP = new Guid("7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99");
        private static Guid GUID_BATTERY_SUBGROUP = new Guid("e73a048d-bf27-4f12-9731-8b2076e8891f");
        private static Guid GUID_SLEEP_SUBGROUP = new Guid("238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20");
        private static Guid GUID_PCIEXPRESS_SETTINGS_SUBGROUP = new Guid("501a4d13-42af-4429-9fd1-a8218c268e20");

        [DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
        static extern uint PowerEnumerate(
            IntPtr RootPowerKey,
            IntPtr SchemeGuid,
            ref Guid SubGroupOfPowerSetting,
            uint AccessFlags,
            uint Index,
            ref Guid Buffer,
            ref uint BufferSize);

        [DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
        static extern uint PowerGetActiveScheme(
            IntPtr UserRootPowerKey,
            ref IntPtr ActivePolicyGuid);

        [DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
        static extern uint PowerReadACValue(
            IntPtr RootPowerKey,
            IntPtr SchemeGuid,
            IntPtr SubGroupOfPowerSettingGuid,
            ref Guid PowerSettingGuid,
            ref int Type,
            ref IntPtr Buffer,
            ref uint BufferSize
            );

        [DllImport("powrprof.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern uint PowerReadFriendlyName(
            IntPtr RootPowerKey,
            IntPtr SchemeGuid,
            IntPtr SubGroupOfPowerSettingGuid,
            IntPtr PowerSettingGuid,
            StringBuilder Buffer,
            ref uint BufferSize
            );

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LocalFree(
            IntPtr hMem
            );

        private const uint ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234;

        public static void GetCurrentPowerEnumerateVistaAPI()
        {
            IntPtr activeGuidPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                uint res = PowerGetActiveScheme(IntPtr.Zero, ref activeGuidPtr);
                if (res != 0)
                    throw new Win32Exception();

                //Get Friendly Name
                uint buffSize = 0;
                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                Guid subGroupGuid = Guid.Empty;
                Guid powerSettingGuid = Guid.Empty;
                res = PowerReadFriendlyName(IntPtr.Zero, activeGuidPtr,
                    IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, buffer, ref buffSize);

                if (res == ERROR_MORE_DATA)
                {
                    buffer.Capacity = (int)buffSize;
                    res = PowerReadFriendlyName(IntPtr.Zero, activeGuidPtr,
                        IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, buffer, ref buffSize);
                }

                if (res != 0)
                    throw new Win32Exception();

                Console.WriteLine("ReadFriendlyName = " +
                    buffer.ToString());

                //Get the Power Settings
                Guid VideoSettingGuid = Guid.Empty;
                uint index = 0;
                uint BufferSize = Convert.ToUInt32(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Guid)));

                while (
                    PowerEnumerate(IntPtr.Zero, activeGuidPtr, ref GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP,
                    18, index, ref VideoSettingGuid, ref BufferSize) == 0)
                {
                    uint size = 4;
                    IntPtr temp = IntPtr.Zero;
                    int type = 0;
                    res = PowerReadACValue(IntPtr.Zero, activeGuidPtr, IntPtr.Zero,
                        ref VideoSettingGuid, ref type, ref temp, ref size);

                    IntPtr pSubGroup = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP));
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP, pSubGroup, false);
                    IntPtr pSetting = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(VideoSettingGuid));
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(VideoSettingGuid, pSetting, false);

                    uint builderSize = 200;
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder((int)builderSize);
                    res = PowerReadFriendlyName(IntPtr.Zero, activeGuidPtr,
                        pSubGroup, pSetting, builder, ref builderSize);
                    Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString() + " = " + temp.ToString());

                    index++;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (activeGuidPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    IntPtr res = LocalFree(activeGuidPtr);
                    if (res != IntPtr.Zero)
                        throw new Win32Exception();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting output from this code:

[image: Power Settings]

Comment: It looks like we're using a bunch of .dlls. Where can I find documentation on them?

Comment: powrprof.dll appears to be included in newer versions of Windows (Vista & newer) according to the [MSDN `PowerEnumerate` page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372730(v=vs.85).aspx)(see bottom of page), and kernel32.dll (the LocalFree function) has been part of Windows since at least XP: [LocalFree on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366730(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I am trying the sample code but I noticed that when I change an individual setting in Power Options dialog. It does not reflect when I rerun the sample. For example, I'm on the Balanced plan and I changed the "Minimum processor state" from 5% to 100%, but the output will always show 5%. Is there any reason for this? How do I get the correct value?

Answer (score 1):

However the accepted answer is still valid, I want to point out there is a bug in it, causing it to enumerate all the default values instead of the actual values.

When reading AC Values it also requires for the sub group guid to be passed:

```
res = PowerReadACValue(IntPtr.Zero, activeGuidPtr, pSubGroup, ref settingGuid, ref type, ref temp, ref size);
```

Comment: I'm reading the battery settings, and this always returns zeros regardless of whether the settings are default or not...

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this post looking for a similar solution and found and corrected a few bugs.

My IDE (visual studio 2019) required a main function so I had to figure out where thats supposed to be in this rather complex code. Finally I tried renaming `GetCurrentPowerEnumerateVistaAPI()` to `Main()`. I have also incorporated @Martijn Spaan fix with a slight change. instead of `ref settingGuid` add `ref videoSettingGuid`.

So now it looks like this and functions as expected:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace TestProject
{
    class PowerEnumerator
    {
        private static Guid NO_SUBGROUP_GUID = new Guid("fea3413e-7e05-4911-9a71-700331f1c294");
        private static Guid GUID_DISK_SUBGROUP = new Guid("0012ee47-9041-4b5d-9b77-535fba8b1442");
        private static Guid GUID_SYSTEM_BUTTON_SUBGROUP = new Guid("4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347");
        private static Guid GUID_PROCESSOR_SETTINGS_SUBGROUP = new Guid("54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00");
        private static Guid GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP = new Guid("7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99");
        private static Guid GUID_BATTERY_SUBGROUP = new Guid("e73a048d-bf27-4f12-9731-8b2076e8891f");
        private static Guid GUID_SLEEP_SUBGROUP = new Guid("238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20");
        private static Guid GUID_PCIEXPRESS_SETTINGS_SUBGROUP = new Guid("501a4d13-42af-4429-9fd1-a8218c268e20");

        [DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
        static extern uint PowerEnumerate(
            IntPtr RootPowerKey,
            IntPtr SchemeGuid,
            ref Guid SubGroupOfPowerSetting,
            uint AccessFlags,
            uint Index,
            ref Guid Buffer,
            ref uint BufferSize);

        [DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
        static extern uint PowerGetActiveScheme(
            IntPtr UserRootPowerKey,
            ref IntPtr ActivePolicyGuid);

        [DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
        static extern uint PowerReadACValue(
            IntPtr RootPowerKey,
            IntPtr SchemeGuid,
            IntPtr SubGroupOfPowerSettingGuid,
            ref Guid PowerSettingGuid,
            ref int Type,
            ref IntPtr Buffer,
            ref uint BufferSize
            );

        [DllImport("powrprof.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern uint PowerReadFriendlyName(
            IntPtr RootPowerKey,
            IntPtr SchemeGuid,
            IntPtr SubGroupOfPowerSettingGuid,
            IntPtr PowerSettingGuid,
            StringBuilder Buffer,
            ref uint BufferSize
            );

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LocalFree(
            IntPtr hMem
            );

        private const uint ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234;

        public static void Main()
        //public static void GetCurrentPowerEnumerateVistaAPI()
        {
            IntPtr activeGuidPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                uint res = PowerGetActiveScheme(IntPtr.Zero, ref activeGuidPtr);
                if (res != 0)
                    throw new Win32Exception();

                //Get Friendly Name
                uint buffSize = 0;
                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                Guid subGroupGuid = Guid.Empty;
                Guid powerSettingGuid = Guid.Empty;
                res = PowerReadFriendlyName(IntPtr.Zero, activeGuidPtr,
                    IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, buffer, ref buffSize);

                if (res == ERROR_MORE_DATA)
                {
                    buffer.Capacity = (int)buffSize;
                    res = PowerReadFriendlyName(IntPtr.Zero, activeGuidPtr,
                        IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, buffer, ref buffSize);
                }

                if (res != 0)
                    throw new Win32Exception();

                Console.WriteLine("ReadFriendlyName = " +
                    buffer.ToString());

                //Get the Power Settings
                Guid VideoSettingGuid = Guid.Empty;
                uint index = 0;
                uint BufferSize = Convert.ToUInt32(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Guid)));

                while (
                    PowerEnumerate(IntPtr.Zero, activeGuidPtr, ref GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP,
                    18, index, ref VideoSettingGuid, ref BufferSize) == 0)
                {
                    uint size = 4;
                    IntPtr temp = IntPtr.Zero;
                    int type = 0;

                    // My chenges
                    IntPtr pSubGroup = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP));
                    res = PowerReadACValue(IntPtr.Zero, activeGuidPtr, pSubGroup, ref VideoSettingGuid, ref type, ref temp, ref size);
                    // end my changes

                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP, pSubGroup, false);
                    IntPtr pSetting = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(VideoSettingGuid));
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(VideoSettingGuid, pSetting, false);

                    uint builderSize = 200;
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder((int)builderSize);
                    res = PowerReadFriendlyName(IntPtr.Zero, activeGuidPtr,
                        pSubGroup, pSetting, builder, ref builderSize);
                    Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString() + " = " + temp.ToString());

                    index++;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (activeGuidPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    IntPtr res = LocalFree(activeGuidPtr);
                    if (res != IntPtr.Zero)
                        throw new Win32Exception();
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```